# differential equation of 4th order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know how to get a general solution for higher-order linear ordinary differential equation (4th order)? 
My equation is $$y''''=-4k^4y$$ where k is a constant.
Then I get: $$λ^4=-4k^4 \implies λ=-\sqrt2\,ki$$

What is a general solution to this?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: hi and welcome to the site, please consider learning mathjax typesetting. the particular 4th order equation you have you can solve by solving a second degree twice. first substitute $a=\lambda ^2$ and solve for a. then substitute back and solve for $\lambda$

Comment: the second problem is to know what happens when taking square root of a complex number. oh i see you already got an answer.

Comment: By the way, the third derivative is often the last one where it's typologically sound to keep using primes. After that, the notation $y^{(n)}$ is generally clearer. So you could write $y^{(4)}=-4k^4 y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots will be $\lambda = (\pm 1 \pm i )k$ giving a general solution of 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=Ae^{kx} \cos(kx)+Be^{kx} \sin(kx)+Ce^{-kx} \cos(kx)+De^{-kx} \sin(kx)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $A,B,C,D$ are arbitary constants.

Comment: So the number of constants depent on the order of DE?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: That's right ... an $n^{th}$ order equation will be a linear combination of $n$ independent solutions.

Comment: May I ask how did you get roots?
Did you solve equation as mathreadler suggested?

Comment: $\lambda^4=-4k^4$ gives $\lambda= \sqrt{2} e^{(i \pi +2ki  \pi )/4}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.